# Are browsers still vulnerable to Cross-Site Cooking?

Tags: appsec, web-application, web-browser, cookies

The [latest article](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5EP0L2KHFG.html) that I have been able to find about [Cross-Site cooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_cooking) was stating that it was possible to set cookie on 2 dots top level domain such as `.co.uk`.

> The mechanism for preventing overly relaxed cookie domain specification seems to be broken in all major browsers.

However this article is dated of 2006. Is this affirmation still true ?

Comment: You may wish to edit your post to refer to the baked goods rather than the process of creating them.

Answer (score 6):

It is believed that browsers can deal with this issue today. However, this is not only the problem of browsers and they are not the general cause of this failure. But to make my answer complete, I would like to direct you to good blog post that is written by Michal Zalewski: http://lcamtuf.blogspot.com/2010/10/http-cookies-or-how-not-to-design.html.