# How important are my cookies from a security perspective?

Tags: web-browser, cookies

If a hacker makes a copy of all my browsing cookies, what could he/she do with that? What are the worst case scenarios?

Comment: See this relevant question: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/595/9792 .

Comment: Thanks but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Down voting without comments is really cool!

Comment: This was a comment to help you improve your question on the basis of previous ones on the same topic (I didn't down vote this short but relevant question).

Comment: The second comment was not for you Daniel :-)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what is in your cookie and how the web application use it. Let say, it is your logged-in session id/cookie (that you have not logged out), it could represent your identity. That means he can go in do whatever he wants, depending on the web application, including changing your password and take over your account.

Answer (score 1):

This varies depending on the sites you use and how they treat them. In most cases where you don't have to login on returning to a site, the person who has copied your cookies would receive the same treatment.

How well this is implemented varies between sites. It could be as ugly as storing your actual password in the cookie (rare, but not unseen) or as good as providing a unique cookie for each sign in and providing a tool to revoke individual or all sessions.

Many implementations will revoke access on a password change and require that the old password be provided to set a new password, thus providing some manner of regaining control.

Answer (score 1):

The core of the problem is that a web server is building **trust** on the basis of **cookies** which are under control of:

- you,
- your web browser,
- any malware which could steal or modify them,
- any hacker which may steal them by spying upon an `http` connection.

Among the worst case scenario you have:

- as user `bob`, by accident or edition of your cookies, you get access as `alice` to the web server and hence to `alice` data,
- a hacker may get a full access as `bob` to his web server,
- a hacker may get a full access as `bob` but with a fake history of other visited web server, hence building a fake history of `bob` browsing
  (`bob` arrived on `linkedin.com` redirected from `big-dick.com`).